# While automating using html code to locate element by id to send keys some values are changing in each refresh in the site

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, ui-automation, inspector

While automating using html code to locate elements by id to send keys some values are changing in each refresh in the siteWhile automating using html code to locate element by id to send keys some values are changing in each refresh in the site.
For example Username has input_0 and password input_1 and after refreshing or make the login the go back to login screen the value is increased !

Is there a way that we can make it always by default (not increased).

Here are 2 example to understand what i'm talking about username in the first one is input_0 (the origin) and in the other is input_4 (for the same field)
[image: problem origin]
[image: problem]

Comment: How is the id being set in the first place? Are you repeatedly creating a form with javascript and automatically setting the id? Perhaps you are not resetting a variable or clearing out the previously created DOM elements when you do so.

Comment: I'm just doing the test i don't know too much how it was coded. It 's in angular js. I just make inspect element then i copy the xpath and see what is the id there.

Comment: I am gonna go off on a limb and say generally the ID for the exact same element should not change dynamically. A work around for this is in the answer @alecxe posted below, but since you said you're not the one doing the coding, I would tell your programmer to review his/her code.

Comment: Finally i'm locating elements by tag name i find that this is the suitable solution for that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used tagName instead of Id in order to locate element to make automation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `id`s to locate elements, especially if they change dynamically and are not reliable enough. Instead, I'd use the `by.model` approach:

```
var usernameInput = element(by.model("credentials.username"));
```

If you then, say, need to locate the corresponding label, you can do it this way:

```
var usernameLabel = usernameInput.element(by.xpath("preceding-sibling::label"));
```

Or, using the `id` of the `input`:

```
usernameInput.getAttribute("id").then(function(id) {
    var usernameLabel = $("label[for=" + id + "]");
});
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe for your answer, finally i'm using tagName to locate all elements in the application.